# Displaying Drill hole data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a large dataset of multiple drill holes that have been tested. The sheet is an excel sheet and contains the holeID, depth, easting, northing and assay results.

example:

[image]

Is there a way I could get Qgis to display the highest down hole value for each drill hole?

Comment: for QGIS3 there is a Geoscience Plugin (displays drill hole data): https://rolandhill.github.io/geoscience/ and for QGIS2 you can make it with the Midvatten plugin: https://github.com/jkall/qgis-midvatten-plugin/wiki

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way. I have two layers, one is a plain table layer with no geometry that you can create from a sheet in a spreadsheet file. Its attribute table looks like this (I've copied your example but simplified the names):

[image]

Then I have a layer, `points` with matching `ID` in its attributes, which looks like this:

[image]

It has one feature per borehole ID. You should probably create this from your spreadsheet by getting a sheet with one row for each borehole with just the ID and coordinates in it. That way you then have a layer with one point per borehole, regardless of how many samples taken at each borehole.

The `maxAU` column is what you want to create. This I made by opening the layer's attribute table and adding a new attribute created by an expression - click the "abacus" button. The expression is:

```
 aggregate( 'data', 'max', "Au", "ID"=attribute(@parent, 'ID'))
```

This says that the value in the new column in `points` will come from the layer called `data`, and it will be the `max`imum value of the `"Au"` column in `data`, but only in the rows that match the `"ID"` value in `data` with the `"ID"` value in the "parent" feature, which is the feature in the `points` layer. The result is the `maxAU` column in the table above.

You can then use that value in QGIS' mapping engine to colour or scale points.

You'll have to repeat this by hand for all the different elements in your data, or find some way of automating it...

Comment: Thank you! What I ended up doing was creating new columns for northing & easting  in the assay table - and then set the symbology to graduated